# Media Query Being Ignored

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have two logos: one for small screens and one for large ones.

Rather than different resolutions of the same image, these are two very different `.png` files and thus I can not use a scaling function. In my attempt to use them, I created the following `media queries` in a `.jsp` page with the purpose of editing a div box in order to show the files as `background-images`:

```css
<style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .zachery_div {
    background: url(/assets/img/LargeLogo.png);
        width: 764px;
        height: 76px;
        float: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .zachery_div {      
     background: url(/assets/img/SmallLogo.png);
        width: 262px;
        height: 76px;
        float: right;
  }
}
</style>
```

However, this only gives me the smaller logo when the `width` of the window is below `1199px`.

If I expand the window to `1200px` or above I receive nothing.

Both images are valid because swapping their position allows me to call either one, but never both.

Can any of you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

When using mobile first approach (`min-width`) the smaller values come first, so your code would be:

```css
.zachery_div {
  height: 76px;
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .zachery_div {
    background: url(/assets/img/SmallLogo.png);
    width: 262px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .zachery_div {
    background: url(/assets/img/LargeLogo.png);
    width: 764px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Note that `meta tag` shouldn't be inside `style` tag. but inside `head` before `style`

And since you had repeated properties, I put them outside of `@media` as they are "standard"  across the code